# Folder other than Source Packages missing on Netbeans?

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-platform, netbeans-8

i have been creating project in netbeans, it been a while since i coding in it but on the next day all folder except Source Packages is missing in the Projects tab tree such as Libraries, Dependencies and other Folder.

How is this happen and how to resolve this.

thanks.

Comment: Can you post the screenshot for the same? It is not clear yet.

Comment: in the end i reinstall netbeans. thanks anyway